# Sum elements with same value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reduce

I have an array like this:

```
[{ "x": 2020-06-27T11:26:00.000Z, "y": 499 },
 { "x": 2020-06-27T11:30:00.000Z, "y": 21 }]
```

I want to sum the `y` values that fall within every two hour intervals (`x`). The `y` values should be combined for intervals 0-2am, 2-4am, 4-6am and so on.

What I've done so far is summing the elements with the same hour:

```js
var t = {};

unsortedData.forEach((v) => {
    if (t[v.x.getHours()]) {
        t[v.x.getHours()] += v.y;
    } else {
        t[v.x.getHours()] = v.y;
    }
});

unsortedData = t;
```

This returns me something like: `{"13": 512, "15": 98..}` and so on.

Now, there are a few issues with this code I don't know how to fix.

First is how can I make it work with two-hour intervals instead of the same hour check?
Also is there is any way to get a return of a full date instead of just hours?

Comment: All values (y) appear to be ints. Whats your logic on using `parseFloat()`? I also should add appear to be in literal format. So why is any *parse* needed?

Comment: So the `x` values are `Date` objects, I assume? If you want the full date, that would need to be stringified for keys, and it's unclear how the 2 hour interval should be encoded. What is the exact result structure you want? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: `Date` is not based on float.

Comment: @GetSet fixed that.

Comment: What is this and why `if(t[v.x.getHours()])`? You are not showing all your code.

Comment: t is just an. empty object create before the loop.

Comment: My recommendation would be to _sort_ the whole array by `x`, _reduce_ the array into groups (2 hour intervals) and _sum_ the group during reduce if a new interval is encountered (to minimize any further iteration).

Comment: @chazsolo thanks for the advice. As for array, it's already pre-sorted by 'x' (from earliest to the latest date). Can you please give some code example or answer of how can I combine reduce and sum there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume in your original data the `x` properties have `Date` instances, since you call `getHours()` on those values.

You can clear the least significant bit of the hour component of your date values, so that they will truncate to a multiple of 2. Use `UTC***` methods though, and pass these date components to the `Date.UTC` method, since your dates were initialised with UTC strings. That gives you a Unix epoch number, which you can use as property for your `t` object (consider using a more meaningful name).

I would however store the complete object in those `t` properties, so that at the end you can extract the object values, and end up with exactly the same format as you started with:

```js
let unsortedData = [
    { "x": new Date("2020-06-27T11:26:00.000Z"), "y": 499 }, 
    { "x": new Date("2020-06-27T11:30:00.000Z"), "y": 21 },
    { "x": new Date("2020-06-27T12:01:00.000Z"), "y": 15 },
    { "x": new Date("2020-06-27T13:59:00.000Z"), "y": 8 },
    { "x": new Date("2020-06-27T14:20:00.000Z"), "y": 30 },
    { "x": new Date("2020-06-27T14:25:00.000Z"), "y": 1 },
];

let t = {};
unsortedData.forEach((v) => {
    let block = Date.UTC(
        v.x.getUTCFullYear(), 
        v.x.getUTCMonth(), 
        v.x.getUTCDate(), 
        v.x.getUTCHours() & 0xFE // ignore last bit of hours binary
    );
    if (t[block]) {
        t[block].y += v.y;
    }
    else
        t[block] = { x: new Date(block), y: v.y };
});
let sortedData = Object.values(t);

console.log(sortedData);
```